# There is already an open datareader error when filling Gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have looked at several posts already on trying to fix this issue and none of them are working. 
I'm already using multiple active results. 
I'm making sure to close the reader connections. 
I'm using a different connection.
I'm using unique names for the reader, datatable, the reader, the command...
I am stuck.

The error is: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

I have marked the error line with "*****error here *****".

Code:

```
    protected void gridviewsched_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string nametime;
    string name;
    string time;
    string initid;
    string timeinitid = null;
    GridView gridviewschedsub = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gridviewschedsub");
    GridView gridviewschedcplt = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gridviewschedcplt");

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Public\\public website\\slDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable dz = new DataTable();
        dz.Columns.Add("age");
        dz.Columns.Add("sex");
        dz.Columns.Add("address");
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            string id = gridviewsched.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT age,sex,address FROM precordTable WHERE Id='" + id + "'", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //List<string> namedatelist = new List<string>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dz.NewRow();
                        dr["age"] = reader[0].ToString();
                        dr["sex"] = reader[1].ToString();
                        dr["address"] = reader[2].ToString();
                        dz.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                gridviewschedsub.DataSource = dz;
                gridviewschedsub.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
            using (var cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, initid FROM precordTable WHERE Id='" + id + "'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd3.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    List<string> namedatelist = new List<string>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        name = reader["name"].ToString();
                        initid = reader["initid"].ToString();
                        time = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
                        time = Regex.Replace(time, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
                        namedatelist.Add(name + time);
                        timeinitid = time + "$" + initid;

                    }
                    Session["timeinitid"] = timeinitid;
                    nametime = Regex.Replace(namedatelist[0].ToString(), "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
                    reader.Close();
                }

            }
            var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select case when exists((select * from [C:\\USERS\\PUBLIC\\PUBLIC WEBSITE\\SLDATABASE.MDF].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_name = 'D" + timeinitid + "ou')) then 1 else 0 end", con);

            if ((int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            {

                string fQuery = "select item, scheduled from D" + timeinitid + "ou where 0 = 1";
                string pQuery = "select item, scheduled from D" + timeinitid + "ou where initialed = '' and prescdr IS NULL and item != '';";
                SqlDataAdapter sdyn = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable cpltTable = new DataTable();

                cpltTable = GetData(pQuery);

                gridviewschedcplt.DataSource = cpltTable;
                gridviewschedcplt.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                return;
            }



        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < gridviewsched.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 3; i < 9; i++)
        {
            gridviewsched.Rows[j].Cells[i].RowSpan = 2;
        }
        gridviewsched.Rows[j].Cells[2].RowSpan = 2;
    }
}

private static DataTable GetData(string pQuery)
{
    string schedtime;
    string nowtime;
    SqlDataAdapter sd1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Public\\public website\\slDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd33 = new SqlCommand(pQuery, conn);
        using (SqlDataReader reader99 = cmd33.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader99.Read())
            {
                sd1.SelectCommand = cmd33;
                ***error here**** sd1.Fill(dTable);
                DataRow newcpltTablerow = dTable.NewRow();
                newcpltTablerow["item"] = reader99["item"].ToString();
                dTable.Rows.Add(newcpltTablerow);

            }

            reader99.Close();
        }

        return dTable;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `SqlDataReader` if you are using a `SqldataAdapter`. You are getting the error because you open a reader within an already open adapter. Do this instead (not compiled so tweak as needed and change the query to yours):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow that was the problem. I actually ended up eliminating the adapter. I only posted about 1/3 of the code in that function and I needed the reader to do some additional operations with the columns.

Answer (score 1):

cmd33.ExecuteReader can only be called once.  You are executing it for each row.